# Gravitational potential of a spherical shell of constant density

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

This question is from Marsden and Tromba's Vector Calculus, 5th Edition, pages 403-404.

Suppose I have a hollow ball $W$ of constant mass density, defined by inner radius $\rho=\rho_1$ and outer radius $\rho = \rho_2$. I am using symmetry to argue that the gravitational potential on the z-axis, $V(x,y,z)=V(0,0,R)$, which can be expressed as

$V(0,0,R) = \displaystyle
\iiint_W \dfrac{dxdydz}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(z-R)^2}} = \int_{\rho_1}^{\rho_2}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \dfrac{\rho^2\sin\phi d\theta d\phi d\rho}{\sqrt{\rho^2\sin^2\phi(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)+(\rho\cos\phi-R)^2}}$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ = \dfrac{2\pi}{R} \displaystyle\int_{\rho_1}^{\rho_2}\rho(\rho+R-|\rho-R|)d\rho$

We have three cases:

Case 1. $R \geq \rho_2$, i.e. $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ is outside of $W$, in which case $|\rho-R|=R-\rho$ for all $\rho$ in the interval $[\rho_1,\rho_2]$, so that

$V(0,0,R) = -\dfrac{2\pi}{R} \displaystyle\int_{\rho_1}^{\rho_2}\rho(\rho+R-(R-\rho))d\rho$

Case 2. $R \leq \rho_1$, i.e. $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ is outside of $W$, in which case $|\rho-R|=\rho-R$ for all $\rho$ in the interval $[\rho_1,\rho_2]$, so that

$V(0,0,R) = -\dfrac{2\pi}{R} \displaystyle\int_{\rho_1}^{\rho_2}\rho(\rho+R-(\rho-R))d\rho$

**I am stuck on expressing the integral for the gravitational potential V(0,0,R) in case 3**, where $\rho_1<R<\rho_2$. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

[Edit] Sorry, edited for adding the negative signs that I had forgotten!

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. It was simply adding the two cases.

Case 3. $\rho_1 \lt R \lt \rho_2$, i.e. $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ is inside the solid region of $W$, in which case $|\rho-R|=R-\rho$ for $\rho \gt \rho_1$ in the interval $[\rho_1,\rho_2]$ and $|\rho-R| = \rho-R$ for all $\rho \lt \rho_2$, so that

$V(0,0,R) = -\dfrac{2\pi}{R} \displaystyle\int_{\rho_1}^{R}\rho(\rho+R-(R-\rho))d\rho -\dfrac{2\pi}{R} \displaystyle\int_{R}^{\rho_2}\rho(\rho+R-(\rho-R))d\rho$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ =-\dfrac{GM(3r^2-R^2)}{2r^3}$

REMARKS

At the center of the ball, the gravitational potential will be $V(0,0,0) = \dfrac{-3GM}{2r}$.

Lastly, at the surface of the ball, the gravitational potential will be $V(0,0,r) = \dfrac{GM}{r}$, which agrees with the gravitational potential formula for a point mass $M$ located $r$ units of distance away from the particle being influenced by gravity.